# extending / changing values of an attribute of a property when extending a class

Tags: c#, attributes

Is it possible to 'change' values of an attribute, when extending classes?  Something similar to below:

```
public class Mammal
{
    [Validation(Required=true, HelpMessage="This is the body shape of a mammal")]
    public virtual string BodyShape { get; set; }

}

public class Dog : Mammal
{
    [Validation(HelpMessage = "This is the body shape of a dog")]
    public override string BodyShape
    {
        get
        {
            return base.BodyShape;
        }
        set
        {
            base.BodyShape = value;
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to be able to read the attribute for Dog.BodyShape, and get it as Required=True, and HelpMessage = "This is the body shape of a dog".  Is this possible?  If not, any suggested alternatives where one can add 'meta-data' information to properties, directly in the compiler?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can inherit attributes; they are attached to a specific method/class.
You could however change the standard implementation of the validation to also check the base classes similarly named properties.

Comment: Attributes are inherited, depending on the value of the AttributeUsage.Inherited property (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tw5zxet9(v=vs.110).aspx)